# OPT3001 conversion formula / equation?

Tags: microcontroller, sensor, c, i2c, conversion

I am struggling to find a real conversion formula for converting the RAW value into result that makes sense. I am using an **[OPT3001](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opt3001.pdf)** sensor from TI and **ATTiny25** as MUC.

I have found one example online, but it does not give the correct value in Lux, the equation used there is this:

```
/*Convert to LUX*/
//extract result & exponent data from raw readings
result = raw&0x0FFF;
exponent = (raw>>12)&0x000F;
lux=0.01*pow(2,eksponent)*result;
```

This gives wrong values according to my Lux meter that I have as refference and, for example, lux meter says its **420 lux** inside Office.. the equation above gives me the result **110 Lux**, which is not realistic. Sensor is working fine as I replaced it new one, in order to be 100% that it is not sensor related issue.

The result is very close if I taked only `result = raw&0x0FFF;` , but then it fails at higher values (when I put my sensor under the Lamp light bulb).

I do not think it's an error inside my I2C code, but I will attach here also the part of my coude for UpdateLight:

```
// I2C OPT address
#define OPT_ADDR_W  0x88
#define OPT_ADDR_R  0x89

// I2C OPT registers
#define OPT_RESULT_REG  0x00
#define OPT_CONFIG_REG  0x01

// OPT config bits - automatic full scale mode, 100 ms conversion, single-shot
#define OPT_CONFIGURATION_H 0xC2
#define OPT_CONFIGURATION_L 0x00

void UpdateLight(void)
{
    uint8_t error = 0;
    // start conversion
    I2C_Start();
    error |= I2C_Write(OPT_ADDR_W);
    error |= I2C_Write(OPT_CONFIG_REG);
    error |= I2C_Write(OPT_CONFIGURATION_H);
    error |= I2C_Write(OPT_CONFIGURATION_L);
    I2C_Stop();

    // wait for conversion
    _delay_ms(150);

    // set result register
    I2C_Start();
    error |= I2C_Write(OPT_ADDR_W);
    error |= I2C_Write(OPT_RESULT_REG);
    I2C_Stop();

    // read data and update scratchpad
    I2C_Start();
    error |= I2C_Write(OPT_ADDR_R);
    if (error == 0)
    {
        scratchpad[1] = I2C_Read(1);
        scratchpad[0] = I2C_Read(0);
    }
    else
    {
        // report error value
        scratchpad[1] = 0xFF;
        scratchpad[0] = 0xFF;
    }
    I2C_Stop();
    }
```

And this is my old formula that I came up with, but it gives even more ridiculous results than the above one from the internet:

```
   // calculate light ( LUX = (MANTISA << EXPONENT) / 100 )
   light = (int16_t)((float)((uint32_t)((spad[SPAD_MSB] << 8) | spad[SPAD_LSB]) << (uint32_t)((spad[SPAD_MSB] >> 4) & 0x0F)) / (83865.60 / LIGHT_MULTIPLIER));
   debug_printf("L_RAW: %02X%02X\r\n", spad[SPAD_MSB], spad[SPAD_LSB]);
   debug_printf("L_VAL: %d\r\n", light);
```

Adding the output lines of the above print statements:

> L: 5460 - 824
>
> L: 5464 - 824
>
> L: 5462 - 824
>
> L: 5462 - 824

The first value should be RAW MSB and LSB, and the second is the converted value to Lux, using the formula above this.

Moreover, I am surprised that inside the Datasheet, TI did not provide a conversion formula ?

Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Comment: What is the raw value you are getting? BTW, it looks(by the conversion example) that the representation is actually a standard floating point one..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Raw1: 5463 , Raw2: 5461  taken at Office Light ambient. The equation above gives me result 148.16Lux, which is incorrect. More closer to real result is if I only take result=raw&0x0FFF ... However, this one then fails at higher brightnes (lamp shining above it). Weird..

Comment: The numbers look suspicious as 5461 in hex is 0x1555 which are alternating zeros and ones. Could it be that you have swapped the SDA and SCL?

Comment: @EugeneSh. hm. Could be, but that I need to check in lab again, wasn't expecting that kind of issue, was hopping it was software oriented. here is one raw example under light: 8437 (hex)

Comment: Oh well, if you have some different values, I guess the connection should be fine.

Comment: BTW, you have not provided the configuration words, it could be that you are just working with some different range you than you are assuming.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have edited my question, if that is what you seek for. Sorry, still not the best with software part.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Config 0xC200

Comment: @Passerby The config looks right, through I am concerned a bit about the bits 10:9. Not quite sure what "shutdown" mode is. Perhaps should be changed to "continuous".

Comment: @EugeneSh. 10:9 is set to 01 with that config. one shot/single conversion mode, That's normal.

Comment: @Passerby Oh, right. Missed one..

Comment: Check TI's [E2E community](https://e2e.ti.com/support/sensor/optical_sensors/), where professionals from TI usually participate a lot. And I do not know but this [question](https://e2e.ti.com/support/sensor/optical_sensors/f/989/t/437260) is maybe the same as yours.

Answer (score 3):

On page `20` of the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opt3001.pdf) the detailed description of the calculation is given. From the given example value from the comments `0x5461` we are getting the `0x5` for the exponent value, which is corresponding to `0.32 lux per LSB`. The mantissa is `0x461` or 1121 in decimal. The resulting value is `1121*0.32=358.72lux` which is close to the expected range.

The working conversion code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main(void) {
    uint16_t raw = 0x5461;
    uint16_t result, exponent;
    float lux;

    result = raw & 0x0FFF;
    exponent = (raw>>12) & 0x000F;

    lux=0.01*(1<<exponent)*result;

    printf("%f\n", lux);
    return 0;
}
```

Or run it [here](https://ideone.com/erDugX).

Please pay a close attention to the datatypes used, they might have causing trouble to you as well..

Comment: so you think that the value 5461¸and others are not HEX values ? You consider them decimal values ?  I thought these were HEX values

Comment: I'm still wondering where that 110 lux are coming from, if I put in the wrong values I get only 27 lux... But yeah endianness is a big trap in data transfer, I guess everyone stumbles upon that.

Comment: I don't know, you tell me. How are you reading them?

Comment: I have added the part of the code where I convert the raw value and then print it out.

Comment: @AndroidNFC if there is no indication (like hex or 0x or _h) most people will read them as decimal. If you take those values as hex, you end up with 360 lux and not 148 lux as stated in your comment.

Comment: So what exactly are the outputs of the prints?

Comment: @Arsenal I mentioned that I am not very good at programming yet, so the code could be a bit messy due to help of internet and others. But as I understood the printed values should be in HEY. With the equation above in my question (the first one), I recieve value 148 lux = 0.01*2exp5*463

Comment: @EugeneSh. From my understanding and from datasheet, they should be the MSB and LSB bytes.

Comment: I mean the actual output lines, can you show them? Anyway, the result from this number in any case should be 360lux, which could be in the range.

Comment: @AndroidNFC Don't forget in you calculation, that `463` are in hex.

Comment: I guess the endianness part of the answer is irrelevant, than.

Comment: @Arsenal and Eugene I have edited my question adding the output of print statements.

Comment: Edited the answer to contain only the relevant part..

Comment: @EugeneSh. could you provide me a C code from the Datasheet part that you posted ? I am not sure how to select the 15:12 bits from my result, so that I can store that as exponent, according ot datasheet.

Comment: Look at the update.

Comment: @EugeneSh. thanks for the update. Could you please explain to me, why is there a need to do the AND operations ? (I'm new to C, I mostly develop Android apps, but wanted to do a more electronics project)

Comment: It's too broad for comments and off-topic for the answer. Look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing))

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept your answer, but still I cannot get near the values with my Lux meter, if you try the hex value 843B .. I get 2772.48 Lux and Lux meter said 1864Lux.. it thik 1000 Lux is a big difference.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you with the provided data. Don't forget, that `lux` is a subjective measure (matched to human eye), greatly affected by the wavelengths in addition to the intensity. So you really need to provide identical conditions for both sensors when measuring. And you can try continuous test to check how values are changing when increasing the light or decreasing. If they change gradually without much jumps, it's a good indication they are measured correctly (up to the sensor's bias..)

Comment: @AndroidNFC your reference lux meter and the OPT3001 might have different angular responses making them take different readings, have a look at page 8 where you can see the Normalized Response vs. Angle, if they are different, you will get different readings.

Comment: @Arsenal and Eugene, could possibly be true, because I cuold not place them bot nicely identical below the lamp for example also. And I actually placed sensor more closer to the lamp then the Meter, so if you say tht it's really sensitive, this could explain this differences!

Comment: The result (in lots of 0.01 lux) is the fractional part, multiplied by 2^n, where n is the exponent part.  So, in lots of 0.01 lux, you can just use result = fraction_part << n; where n is the exponent part.  (Right shift N bits is the same as multiply by 2^n).
Thus result = (fraction_part << n) / 100 for whole lux; and where n = the exponent part.